# Firebase Cordova vs Firebase JS SDK?

Tags: firebase, cordova, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I'm building a mobile app based on Cordova. Quick research lead me to these repos:

1. Firebase's official JS SDK library - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk
2. Firebase Cordova implementation - https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

There is no explanation on the Cordova repository on how it differs from the Firebase JS SDK. Since I can run JS on my Cordova app, then my biggest question is why do I need the `cordova-plugin-firebasex` at all? What the added value here?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase JS SDK should work on all platforms (all available features for web) as at the end of the day it is a WebView. But the plugin will allow you to use Android or IOS specific features.

Comment: Is it able to send push notifications for ios?

Comment: I haven't tested yet. But this should work as a WebView is actually a small browser.

Comment: Update: It will not work, as ios webview does not support service workers.

Answer (score 0):

The [firebase js sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) is used only for web while the `cordova-plugin-firebasex` is used for android and ios apps. If you use the `firebase-js-sdk` then you won't be able to send notifications to the android or the ios device. Also the cordova plugin will enable you to use `crashlytics` which you can't use with the js sdk.

Comment: I was able to send push notifications to my android while using the firebase-js only (not sure about the iPhone tho)

Comment: Does this mean that cordova-plugin-firebasex does not work for web? How do you get something that works with all 3?